# Can Different Elf Subraces Produce Offspring?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, elf

We're playing a homebrew D&D 5e game in which the players will all be from an elven kingdom and I'm curious if different subraces of elf are capable of having children together.

For example: Could a Drow and a Wood Elf have children?

Comment: Hi, and welcome. I'm voting to hold this question as "unclear." Some points that I think need addressing: (a) what edition of D&D are you playing? (b) what's the setting (published, organized play, home-game)? (c) what elf-kingdom? (Those may not be all, but they're certainly major ones.) You can [edit] your question to include more information which will then enqueue it for reopening. (And while you wait, go ahead and take a moment to take the [tour].)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is there a possibility"? Are you creating a new character? Is the campaign set in the Forgotten Realms, or a homebrew setting, or a different existing setting? What exactly are you trying to ask - or, in other words, what is the problem you are actually trying to solve? It will help us narrow down your question if we know what you actually want to do/know. (Otherwise, this might end up being an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: Are you asking “can I play a half-dark-elf, half-wood-elf?”?

Comment: Are you asking this as a player or a DM?  If you're asking as a player, then the answer is that you should ask your DM.

Comment: Thank you Ben, that is actually good cause I am asking as a player. But by possibility I mean can a dark and wood elf have a child? Like are they compatible? Its a custom setting I believe, and I am creating a new character. Thank you in advance for clarification. Sorry about the unclear question.

Comment: @Apollo If you're playing in a custom setting, nobody but your DM can answer your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, in a custom world, it's more than opinion-based, it's completely unanswerable.

Comment: @T.J.L. It's not unanswerable. The answer is "It's up to your DM". (And we have lots of questions like these around here.)